# What are all simplifiable fractions k/N (0<=k<=N) called and how can one generate them?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, fractions, coprime

**The problem I am trying to solve is as follows:**

Take a positive integer $N$. Give the function $f$, such that $f(N)$ generates the sequence of all fractions $\frac{k}{N}$ where $(0 \le k \le N)$ such that $\frac{k}{N}$ can be simplified ($k$ and $N$ are not co-prime*)

*This might actually not be sufficient to say (since 0 is co-prime to 1 for example), so below the definition I came up with, that includes 0 and N itself.
***Fractions where the numerator and denominator share some factor.***
*a.k.a some fraction $\frac{i}{j}$ can be found such that $\frac{i}{j} = \frac{k}{N}$ where $\frac{i}{j}$ itself can't be simplified further or an integer $I$ can be found such that $I = \frac{k}{N}$.*

**An example would be:**

Let $N = 12$
Now $f(12) = \{\frac{0}{12} , \frac{2}{12} ,\frac{3}{12} ,\frac{4}{12} ,\frac{6}{12} ,\frac{8}{12} ,\frac{9}{12} ,\frac{10}{12} ,\frac{12}{12} \}$
Which when simplified would become: $f(12) = \{0, \frac{1}{6} ,\frac{1}{4} ,\frac{1}{3} ,\frac{1}{2} ,\frac{2}{3} ,\frac{3}{4} ,\frac{5}{6} ,1 \}$

**My related questions are:**

- What is this sequence called?
- How would one name the sequence of all $GCM(k, N)$ (e.g. $\{0,2,3,4,6,8,9,10,12\}$)
- What would the function to generate this sequence look like?

**Research I have already performed:**

- All factors of $N$ form a subset of the numerators namely up to $\frac{N}{2}$, any numbers between $\frac{N}{2}$ and $N$ are therefore not included.
- All prime numbers generate the sequence $\{0, 1\}$ as they have no factors or numbers with which they share factors.
- I concluded I wanted a sequence of numbers for which the numerator and denominator aren't co-prime , but including $\frac{0}{N}$ and $\frac{N}{N}$

Comment: $0$ and $1$ are co-prime, and $\frac 01$ cannot be simplified - I do not see a probelm there

Comment: Those might be edge cases. $f(1)$ should be $\{0, 1\}$  
basically always including $\frac{0}{N}$ and $\frac{N}{N}$ in the sequence.  
And $\frac{0}{1}$ can be simplified to 0, in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac k N$ can be simplified if and only if $\gcd(k,N)>1$, i.e. if $k$ and $N$ share a common factor. So basically you just want to find all $k\in\{0,\ldots,N\}$ such that $\gcd(k,N)>1$. Probably the easiest way would be this:

There must be some prime number that divides both $p$ and $N$. So find all the prime divisors $p_1, \ldots,p_m$ of $N$, and take all multiples of all the $p_i$'s (up to $N$). That gives all $k$. We will find the some values multiple times though.

Example: $12=2^2\cdot3$. So we take all multiples of $2$ and $3$: $\{0,2,4,6,8,10,12\}$, $\{0,3,6,9,12\}$. We take the union of these, giving
$$
k\in\{0,2,3,4,6,8,9,10,12\}
$$

Using the formula for Euler's totient function, we have a nice expression for the number of values:
$$
\#f(N) = N+1-\varphi(N) =  N+1-N\prod_{p|N}(1-1/p) = 1+N\left(1-\prod_{p|N}(1-1/p)\right)
$$
where the product is taken over the prime divisors of $N$. We can test it for $N=12$:
$$
1+12\left(1-\prod_{p|12}(1-1/p)\right)
= 1+12\left(1-\left(1-\frac12\right)\left(1-\frac13\right)\right)
= 9
$$

By the way, I am not sure your sets really have speciel names (other than just describing them in some way or other), since we tend to study the numbers that *are* coprime to $N$. I could be wrong about that. We could call them the zero-divisors modulo $N$, but that would make more sense in another context.

---

EDIT: We can compare your $f$ to Farey sequences like so:
$$
\mathrm{Farey}(N) = \{\text{reduced fractions } \frac ab\in[0,1] \text{ where }b\le N\}
$$
$$
f(N) = \{\text{reduced fractions } \frac ab\in[0,1] \text{ where } b\mid N, b\ne N\}
$$
Let's find $f(12)$ again with that mindset: First find all proper divisors of $12$: $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$. Then find all irreducible fractions between $0$ an $1$ with these denominators:
$$
\left\{\frac01,\frac11\right\}\cup
\left\{\frac12\right\}\cup
\left\{\frac13,\frac23\right\}\cup
\left\{\frac14,\frac34\right\}\cup
\left\{\frac16,\frac56\right\}
= \left\{0,\frac16,\frac14,\frac13,\frac12,\frac23,\frac34,\frac56,1\right\}
$$
Alternatively, you can take *all* fractions with $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$ as denominators and then reduce them. Then you will find the same reduced fractions multiple times.

We can also use the Farey sequences if we want. If $d$ is the largest proper divisor of $N$, then we can generate the Farey sequence of order $d$ using the algorithm on wikipedia for example. Then we remove all fractions with a denominator that does not divide $N$. For $N=12$ we would find $\mathrm{Farey}(6)$ and remove the terms with denominator $5$.

Comment: This answer really is an amazing way of getting the set of numbers for any N. Where the Farey sequence focuses on the fractions when reduced lie below some number, what you describe stays truer to the bound from 0 to N kind of function. So if I understand it correctly, simply find the prime factorization and take all their multiples and union them. Which a super easy way for my use case.

Comment: @AgentM I made an edit discussing Farey sequences.

Comment: I have marked this as the better answer to my question. This is precisely what I needed. Thank you.